# Zend XmlRpc Client gzinflate out of memory on php 7.1

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc, php-7.1

I have a problem with Zend XmlRpc Client. When it recieves response with more than 25MB, then it crushes with Out of memory error Fatal Error: Allowed memory size....

Can someone help me please with this issue?

I tried to recieve this response with Guzzle Client and it works fine, but it lacks XmlRpc parser, so it's not an option for me. I have a theory that there is something wrong with Zend XmlRpc Client itself. I also tried to set php memory_limit to -1, to 1024M but it not works because it just eats all my RAM and fails with Out of memory error or Fatal Error: Allowed memory size...